# check all filter is exist in database or not

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, motordriver

There are some data in my mongodb collection like this :

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60603f0075ee1d1cdcd95d1a"},
"store_id":{"$oid":"60603dd675ee1d1cdcd95d18"},
"product_id":{"$oid":"6062f6973f24de12f0264013"}}
```

I wanna pass query , my query is list of store_id if all of element of list is exist in database return something like true else if even one of the element not match in database return something like false...

I can check one by one and use findOne ,but i don't wanna to check one by one!

Update:
I can do this by for and findOne but i don't wanna send a lot of query to db !

Comment: Can you include some expected output plz.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat
output some like this to know all data exist in database : {status : True} or {status : false}
i pass array and i wanna get one result ! all of elements exist in database or not !

Comment: Yo want that status field to appear in all documents or are you expecting single object as query output.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat
just single output ! all of them is exist or not !

Answer (score 1):

I could only come up with this: pass the list of store_ids and number of store_ids. Filter for items by store_id and count haw many unique store_ids there, then compare the number with the number of store_ids you passed in the query. You can express this using aggregation.

And if you use aggregation, you always get document (object) back from MongoDB: {'filedA': false}, so you can't get just `false1`.

```
storeIds= [123, 1234, 12345];
numStoreIds = storeIds.length;

pipeline=
[{$match: {
  orderId: {$in: storeIds}
}}, {$group: {
  _id: "$storeId"
}}, {$count: 'num'}, {$project: {
  result: {
    $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$num", numStoreIds ] }, true, false]
  }
}}]

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)

>
{ "result" : true }
```